# I have a problem with Azure Function Bundle Bindings

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have a host.json file on my project with:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

But I want to change the version of extension bundle to version "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"

Always that host.json is generated the version "[2.*, 3.0.0)" is created

Don't have option to change "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)", only "[1.*, 2.0.0)" or "[2.*, 3.0.0)"

I'm using node version 14 on Linux

Comment: 3.x version is required for using 3.3.0, 4.0.0  - version in host.json. Please refer [Extension bundles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles)

Comment: This is my host.json after changes:
{
  "version": "3.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
Is this correct?
My VS Code shows the following warning:
Value is not accepted. Valid values: "2.0".

Comment: I have tried with the 2.0 version only and able to see the 3.3.0, 4.0.0. Update the extensionbundle version in the VSCode and redeploy the app once again and check once

Comment: Check the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbtkT.png).

Answer (score 0):

- We can a specify custom version range in host.json
- Extension bundles are supported for version 2.x and later version of the Functions runtime.
- We cannot edit/update the Published Azure function files
- When you publish your app to Azure Function using Visual Studio Code/Visual Studio or any other CI/CD tool like Azure DevOps, your app is compiled (dll file) and bundled into a zip file, and it also becomes read-only so that you don't try to modify it via Portal editing.

[image]

- If you need to update your app, open code of the app in Visual Studio Code , make changes and publish it again.
- Update the project's host.json file locally and redeploy the application.

[image]

The following table lists the currently available versions of the default *Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle* bundle

[image]